# How to deploy express js api to my godaddy sub domain

Tags: node.js, express, server

I recently get myself a godaddy server. I did the set up that i need to do and have created a sub domain as `api.domain.com` i want to deploy my api from my gitlab to the sub domain.

**what i have done:**

- ssh into the server as default user and used git clone to clone my repo to the api sub folder
- followed an online tutorial to install node on the server.

I'm not sure how to for instance. use postman to to send and get a response from the api. do i just type `api.mydomain.com` and make a request?